# How to implement a lazy property in Kotlin that requires another property?

Tags: kotlin, lazy-initialization, kotlin-delegate

I need a rectangle that needs to be initialized on call.

Here is my code;

```
class EpheButton private constructor(
    private val text: String,
    private val x: Float,
    private val y: Float,
    private val projectionMatrix: Matrix4) : Disposable {
private val spriteBatch: SpriteBatch = SpriteBatch()
private val bitmapFont: BitmapFont = BitmapFont()
private val shapeRenderer: ShapeRenderer = ShapeRenderer()

private val textWidth: Float
private val textHeight: Float
private val rectangle :Rectangle by lazy { Rectangle(x, y, textWidth, textHeight) }

init {
    bitmapFont.data.setScale(2f)
    bitmapFont.region.texture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear)
    bitmapFont.color = Color.BLUE
    val layout = GlyphLayout()
    layout.setText(bitmapFont, text)
    textWidth = layout.width
    textHeight = layout.height
}
```

I get errors for the line `private val rectangle :Rectangle by lazy { Rectangle(x, y, textWidth, textHeight) }` which says that;

> Variable 'textWidth' must be initialized
>   Variable 'textHeight' must be initialized

But I am already initializing them on the `init{}` code block.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In kotlin , you have to initialize a variable before using it, You are using lazy initializer for Rectangle but compiler doesn't know the the status of **textWidth** and **textHeight**

So class looks like this

```
class EpheButton private constructor(
    private val text: String,
    private val x: Float,
    private val y: Float,
    private val projectionMatrix: Matrix4) : Disposable {
private val spriteBatch: SpriteBatch = SpriteBatch()
private val bitmapFont: BitmapFont = BitmapFont()
private val shapeRenderer: ShapeRenderer = ShapeRenderer()

private val textWidth: Float
private val textHeight: Float
init {
    bitmapFont.data.setScale(2f)
    bitmapFont.region.texture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear)
    bitmapFont.color = Color.BLUE
    val layout = GlyphLayout()
    layout.setText(bitmapFont, text)
    textWidth = layout.width
    textHeight = layout.height
}
private val rectangle :Rectangle by lazy { Rectangle(x, y, textWidth, textHeight) }
```

Updated :-
**Why order of initialization matter's here ?**

We can call this weired behavior to [Null-Safty](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) of Kotlin. When we change the order of **init block** and **variable declaration** , we are breaking this rule.

> **From Kotlin official documentaion :-**
>
> Kotlin's type system is aimed to eliminate NullPointerException's from
>   our code. The only possible causes of NPE's may be
>
> 1. An explicit call to throw NullPointerException();
> 2. Usage of the !! operator that is described below;
> 3. External Java code has caused it;
> 4. There's some data inconsistency with regard to initialization (an uninitialized *this* available in a constructor is used somewhere).

Other than this four conditions , it always ensure that a variable is initialized at compile time . so same with our case it just ensuring that the used variable must be initialized before it used.

Comment: Is it not weird that the order is important? I thought that the init code block is guaranteed to be called on the creation of an object. Does not the kotlin compiler know this?

Comment: i am a just beginner in kotlin ,so don't know details too much but i tried to explain my best about this behavior , please see the updated answer . If you find anything wrong or conflicting, don't hesitate to down vote the answer. :)